# Web scraping with bs4 python: How to display football matchups

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm a beginner to Python and am trying to create a program that will scrape the football/soccer schedule from skysports.com and will send it through SMS to my phone through Twilio. I've excluded the SMS code because I have that figured out, so here's the web scraping code I am getting stuck with so far:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.skysports.com/football-fixtures"
page = requests.get(URL)

results = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

d = defaultdict(list)

comp = results.find('h5', {"class": "fixres__header3"})
team1 = results.find('span', {"class": "matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side1"})
date = results.find('span', {"class": "matches__date"})
team2 = results.find('span', {"class": "matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side2"})

for ind in range(len(d)):
    d['comp'].append(comp[ind].text)
    d['team1'].append(team1[ind].text)
    d['date'].append(date[ind].text)
    d['team2'].append(team2[ind].text)
```

Comment: are you wanting to scrape just the top football game or all of them for a specific date?

Comment: All of them for the day’s games. Want it to look something like this: “Saturday February, 21: Premier League: Manchester United vs Chelsea 17:00, Man City vs SHU 18:00, etc.”

Comment: Can you tell us more about what sort of problems you're having? Are you getting errors, erroneous output, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Down below should do the trick for you:

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests
    
    a = requests.get('https://www.skysports.com/football-fixtures')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text,features="html.parser")
    
    teams = []
    for date in soup.find_all(class_="fixres__header2"): # searching in that date
        for i in soup.find_all(class_="swap-text--bp30")[1:]: #skips the first one because that's a heading
            teams.append(i.text)
    
    date = soup.find(class_="fixres__header2").text
    print(date)
    teams = [i.strip('\n') for i in teams]
    for x in range(0,len(teams),2):
        print (teams[x]+" vs "+ teams[x+1])
```

Let me further explain what I have done:
All the football have this class name - *swap-text--bp30*
[image]

So we can use [find_all](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/bs4.BeautifulSoup.find_all) to extract all the classes with that name.

Once we have our results we can put them into an array "teams = []" then append them in a for loop "team.append(i.text)". *".text" strips the html*

Then we can get rid of "\n" in the array by stripping it and printing out each string in the array two by two.
This should be your final output:

[image]

**EDIT:** To scrape the title of the leagues we will do pretty much the same:

```
league = []
for date in soup.find_all(class_="fixres__header2"): # searching in that date
    for i in soup.find_all(class_="fixres__header3"): #skips the first one because that's a heading
        league.append(i.text)
```

Strip the array and create another one:

```
league = [i.strip('\n') for i in league]
final = []
```

Then add this final bit of code which is essentially just printing the league then the two teams over and over:

```
for x in range(0,len(teams),5):
    final.append(teams[x]+" vs "+ teams[x+1])

for i in league:
    print(i)
    for i in final:
        print(i)
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for taking the time and explaining it. 

And thanks to others who commented.

Comment: @aabdall no problem! If you feel you haven't understood a part, I wouldn't mind explaining it in more detail for you as you said you are a beginner in python. If the answer has solved your question, please press the green tick to mark it solved. Thanks :)

Comment: This is great. I was just wondering if there’s any way I can add the competition name before the teams w/o completely altering the code. (Output: Premier League: ....Serie A:...)?  If not, this is already good!

Comment: @aabdall I edited my question, that should all work for you now mate. If not let me know and I can revisit this. I am not really in on football so if I have made a mistake, just tell me! And as previously mentioned, if this does help your question please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it as an answer :P

Comment: @aabdall No problem mate