# Why do parts of the HTML that appear using Inspect Element, not appear after parsing the HTML using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to web scrape MLB Batter Player Prop Lines from DraftKings using Python and Beautiful Soup, but the data that appears while using SelectorGadget or Inspect Element is not in the parsed HTML. The website I am trying to scrape from is: https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/leagues/baseball/mlb?category=batter-props&subcategory=total-bases

I have successfully written the following code to create a data frame containing each player's homerun odds. However, when I change the URL to a different subcategory (i.e. "total-bases"), the CSS selectors tied to each variable no longer appear in the parsed HTML. I am unsure how to make new dataframes if the CSS selectors and the data is not appearing in the parsed HTML. Currently, I am altering the URL variable to change subcategories, but I am open to other suggestions. How should I proceed? Do I need to use a different package than BeautifulSoup?

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/leagues/baseball/mlb?category=batter-props&subcategory=home-runs'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

player_names = \[row.get_text() for row in soup.find_all(class\_="sportsbook-row-name")\]
lines = values = \[float(element.text.replace(",", "")) for element in soup.select("th+ .sportsbook-table__column-row .sportsbook-outcome-cell__line") if element.text.strip()\]
over = \[int(element.text.strip().replace('−', '-')) for element in soup.select("th+ .sportsbook-table__column-row .default-color")\]
under = \[int(element.text.strip().replace('−', '-')) for element in soup.select("td+ .sportsbook-table__column-row .default-color") if element.text.strip().replace('−', '-')\]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Player Name": player_names, "Line": lines, "Over": over, "Under": under})
```

Comment: Print the`response` to see what you have and then figure out how to find interesting parts of it. It probably turns out to be this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233334/beautifulsoup-doesnt-return-the-whole-html-seen-in-inspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Inspect Element feature in web browsers, you are examining the up-to-date state of the DOM after the browser has parsed the HTML and made any required adjustments or JavaScript manipulations.

In contrast, when parsing HTML using BeautifulSoup , you are working directly with the original HTML source code in its unaltered form as received from the server. BeautifulSoup parses the HTML and creates a parse tree, but it does not execute any JavaScript or apply dynamic modifications that may be performed by the browser.Since BeautifulSoup does not execute JavaScript or handle asynchronous requests, the results of these actions will not be reflected in the parsed HTML.